# How to Add Wordpress Conditional Statement if(is_page()) to Display Correctly

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to add a conditional statement to the code below where href="#" is at.  What I want to do is have the page display a link if it's page id 163 and a different link for everything else.

```
    <?php 
if ( function_exists('wp_pagenavi') )
{
    ob_start();
    wp_pagenavi( array( 'type' => 'multipart' ) );

    $pagenavi = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    if ( !strstr($pagenavi, 'nextpostslink') ) $pagenavi = str_replace('</div>', '<a href="#" style="float:right;" rel="next" class="nextpostslink">NEXT &gt;&gt;</a>'."\r".'</div>', $pagenavi);

    echo $pagenavi;
}
?>
```

I'm not sure how to get it to work right.  I've tried adding if else statements inside it but I obviously don't know how to code it properly because the page keeps breaking when i do it.

The way I have it setup right now is that when it reaches the last page for the post it will go to a link that I insert.  What I need it to do is give me the option of 2 different links based on the page id.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php 
if ( function_exists('wp_pagenavi') )
{
    ob_start();
    wp_pagenavi( array( 'type' => 'multipart' ) );

    $pagenavi = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    $link = '<a';
    if (is_page('163')) {
        $link .= ' href="#" ';
    }
    $link .= 'style="float:right;" rel="next" class="nextpostslink">NEXT &gt;&gt;</a>'."\r".'</div>'
    if ( !strstr($pagenavi, 'nextpostslink') ) $pagenavi = str_replace(
    '</div>', $link, $pagenavi);

    echo $pagenavi;
}
?>
```

Comment: It did work but it's missing a ; at the end of one of the lines.  I had to add an else statement to it too.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the correct answer based upon ThemesCreator's answer. He was missing a semicolon and else statement.  And for some reason the is_page wasn't working so I changed it to is_single instead.

```
<?php 
if ( function_exists('wp_pagenavi') )
{
    ob_start();
    wp_pagenavi( array( 'type' => 'multipart' ) );

    $pagenavi = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    $link = '<a';
    if (is_single( '163' )) {
        $link .= ' href="LINK1" ';
    }
    else {
        $link .= ' href="LINK2" ';
    }
    $link .= 'style="float:right;" rel="next" class="nextpostslink">NEXT &gt;&gt;</a>'."\r".'</div>';
    if ( !strstr($pagenavi, 'nextpostslink') ) $pagenavi = str_replace(
    '</div>', $link, $pagenavi);

    echo $pagenavi;
}
?>
```

For anyone wondering what it's for, I used as part of WP Pagenavi to allow me to use other links based on page ID.  This way I can use the next button to go directly where I want it to.